# Mechanism for the chlorination of Fluorene with NCS?

Tags: organic-chemistry

[image]

From literature, it was described that fluorene can react with NCS and conc. HCl to produce the 2,7-diCl derivative. Please help me understand the mechanism.

Comment: I'd always suggest checking the original paper, rather than relying on the one-liner summary from SciFinder / Reaxys. Since you're on SciFinder, it shouldn't be too many extra clicks.

Comment: The source of the reaction conditions presented by the OP is: https://www.thieme-connect.de/products/ejournals/abstract/10.1055/s-1994-25668, which predates the link provided by Waylander.

Answer (score 2):

According to this paper [here](http://www.isca.in/rjcs/Archives/v5/i12/7.ISCA-RJCS-2015-160.pdf)

> it has been described recently that at very low pH ($\mathrm{pH <  3}$)  $\ce{Cl2}$  functions  as  an  active  chlorinating  agent

In the authors' view the system works by $\ce{NCS}$ oxidising chloride to chlorine which then provides $\ce{Cl+}$ as the chlorinating agent.